# Are the latest generation Blackberry smart phones capable of arbitrary IPSec mobile VPN connections?

Tags: blackberry, vpn

Googling around briefly, see references to VPN and WPA2 Enterprise (tunneling in from an untrusted WIFI connection), but unclear whether the Blackberry Bold, Torch, etc. can be used as a generic Mobile IPSec client (Cisco, pfSense, etc.) from the carrier 3G network.

All the pieces seem to be there like certificate store, encryption protocols, etc., but not sure what's required or if at all possible.

Would like to require users to establish a VPN to tunnel into a remote network before accessing a Web application on said remote network with their native Blackberry browsers.

Note: devices are unmanaged and not owned/paid for by the organization, so no BES capabilities.

Answer (score 2):

Well all connection from BB phones goes via the BB server(BB Internet Service). So I dont think there are any tools that does this. A quick search in BB app world for vpn shows only irrelevant applications. The closest I can think of is using https directly to access your web application. But this too will be proxied via the BB proxy servers. So some one there can snoop your traffic if they want to.